# Use cache under mod_wsgi for Python web framework

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

The codes are like this(I'm using flask and [flask-cache](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Cache/#api) but this might be a general problem):

```
@cache.memoize(500000)
def big_foo(a,b):
    return a + b + random.randrange(0, 1000)
```

If I run it in a Python intepreter, I can always get the same result by calling `big_foo(1,2)`.

But if I add this function in the application and use `mod_wsgi` to daemon, then request in browser. (the `big_foo` is called within the views function of that request). I found the result is not the same each time.

I think the results are different each time because `mod_wsgi` use multiple process to launch the app. Each process might have their own cache, and the cache can't be shared between process.

Is my guess right? If right, how can I assign one and only one cache for global accessing? If not, where was wrong with my codes?

Following is the config used for `flask-cache`

```
UPLOADS_FOLDER = "/mnt/Storage/software/x/temp/"                                                                                 
class RadarConfig(object):                                                                                                                   
    UPLOADS_FOLDER = UPLOADS_FOLDER                                                                                                          
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['bed'])                                                                                                        
    SECRET_KEY = "tiananmen"                                                                                                                 
    DEBUG = True                                                                                                                             
    CACHE_TYPE = 'simple'                                                                                                                    
    CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5000000                                                                                                          
    BASIS_PATH = "/mnt/Storage/software/x/NMF_RESULT//p_NMF_Nimfa_NMF_Run_30632__metasites_all"                              
    COEF_PATH = "/mnt/Storage/software/x/NMF_RESULT/MCF7/p_NMF_Nimfa_NMF_Run_30632__metasample_all"                              
    MASK_PATH = "/mnt/Storage/software/x/NMF_RESULT/dhsHG19.bed"
```

Comment: Which cache backend are you using? Could you share the configuration of Flask-Cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem: `CACHE_TYPE = 'simple'`. From `SimpleCache` [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/contrib/cache/#werkzeug.contrib.cache.SimpleCache):

> Simple memory cache for single process environments. This class exists mainly for the development server and is not 100% thread safe.

For production better suited backends are `memcached`, `redis` and `filesystem`, since they're designed to work in concurrent environments.